# Set session to scrape page

Tags: php, http, session, screen-scraping

URL1: `https://duapp3.drexel.edu/webtms_du/`

URL2: `https://duapp3.drexel.edu/webtms_du/Colleges.asp?Term=201125&univ=DREX`

URL3: `https://duapp3.drexel.edu/webtms_du/Courses.asp?SubjCode=CS&CollCode=E&univ=DREX`

As a personal programming project, I want to scrape my University's course catalog and provide it as a RESTful API.

However, I'm running into the following issue.

The page that I need to scrape is URL3. But URL3 only returns meaningful information after I visit URL2 (it sets the term there `Colleges.asp?Term=201125`), but URL2 can only be visited after visiting URL1.

I tried monitoring the HTTP data going to and fro using Fiddler and I don't think they are using cookies. Closing the browser instantly resets everything, so I suspect they are using Session.

How can I scrape URL 3? I tried, programatically, visiting URLs 1 and 2 first, and then doing `file_get_contents(url3)` but that doesn't work (probably because it registers as three different sessions.

Comment: There is a session being set using cookies: `ASPSESSIONIDASBRRCCS` is it's name, though I can't see why URL2 is necessary (might be me, I forgot to pay attention the first time around)

Comment: @Grexis: Ah, thanks for the information. URL3 provides information such as where the class will be held and who will take it. This depends on the term(semester) which seems to be getting set in URL2

Comment: Maybe it's worth mentioning that php is one of the few dynamic languages that doesn't have a mechanize library. For this reason perl python or ruby are all better choices for scraping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A session needs a mechanism to identify you as well. Popular methods include: cookies, session id in URL.

A `curl -v` on URL 1 reveals a session cookie is indeed being set.

```
Set-Cookie: ASPSESSIONIDASBRRCCS=LKLLPGGDFBGGNFJBKKHMPCDA; path=/
```

You need to send this cookie back to the server on any subsequent requests to keep your session alive.

If you want to use `file_get_contents`, you need to manually create a context for it with [`stream_context_create`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.stream-context-create.php) for to include cookies with the request.

An alternative (which I would personally prefer) would be to use [`curl` functions](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php) conveniently provided by PHP. (It can even take care of the cookie traffic for you!) But that's just my preference.

Edit:

Here's a working example to scrape the path in your question.

```
$scrape = array(
    "https://duapp3.drexel.edu/webtms_du/",
    "https://duapp3.drexel.edu/webtms_du/Colleges.asp?Term=201125&univ=DREX",
    "https://duapp3.drexel.edu/webtms_du/Courses.asp?SubjCode=CS&CollCode=E&univ=DREX"
);

$data = '';
$ch = curl_init();

// Set cookie jar to temporary file, because, even if we don't need them, 
// it seems curl does not store the cookies anywhere otherwise or include
// them in subsequent requests
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, tempnam(sys_get_temp_dir(), 'curl'));

// We don't want direct output by curl
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

// Then run along the scrape path
foreach ($scrape as $url) {
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    $data = curl_exec($ch);
}

curl_close($ch);

echo $data;
```

Comment: It seems `curl` is a much better option indeed. How do you use `curl -v`. Fiddler didn't show me the cookie, so it seems I should `curl -v` is a better option. Do you use it from a shell?

Comment: Yes, `curl` is a shell program, `-v` just means `verbose` which will show the request and response headers. Curl man page: http://www.manpagez.com/man/1/curl/

Comment: Perfect. I'm able to receive the cookie and save it to a file. As for sending it in the next request, the man page will help me with that. By the way, once I receive the cookie, for how long it is valid? Does that depend on their config?

Comment: It is valid as long for as you keep sending it to the server. The session on the server will expire at some point, though.

Comment: I'm being able to receive the cookie, and send it back when querying the next url, but I still receive an error back as though no cookies were sent. I'll read up on the man pages, and post another qustion if needed. Thanks!

Comment: @xbonez I updated my answer with a (seemingly) working example.

Comment: In case you can help, please see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8757444/using-curl-to-receive-and-send-cookies-but-not-getting-expected-response