# Using curl to receive and send cookies, but not getting expected response

Tags: http, curl, https

Related question: [Set session to scrape page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8756530/set-session-to-scrape-page)

As a personal project, I'm trying to scrape my University's course catalog to provide it as a RESTful API.

URL1: `https://duapp3.drexel.edu/webtms_du/`

URL2: `https://duapp3.drexel.edu/webtms_du/Colleges.asp?Term=201125&univ=DREX`

Going to URL1 sets a cookie which is needed for URL2. I'm successfully receiving and sending the cookie like this:

`curl -c recd url1

curl -v -b recd url2`

However, the response I get differs from the one I see in my browser. Basically, my browser shows me a list of majors, while `curl` gets a page where instead of the list of majors, it has

`<FONT COLOR=red size=5> The lists of subjects are not available online for the selected term at this time.</FONT><FONT COLOR=red size=5> Please check back again later.</FONT>`

I figured maybe they were checking user-agent, so I tried this as well:

`curl -b recdcookies --user-agent "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 5.01; Windows NT 5.0)" https://duapp3.drexel.edu/webtms_du/Colleges.asp?Term=201125&univ=DREX`

But same unexpected response.

What is causing the different outputs between browser and curl? As far as `curl -v` shows it only sets one cookie. Is it because they are `https` pages, and I need to be adding another argument to the `curl` ?

Comment: Are you including the cookie from first request in the second request?

Comment: @nikc.org I am. Initially when I wasn't, the page returned had a message saying 'invalid arguments...'. Now it returns but without the list of courses, so I think the cookies are going fine

Comment: Perhaps a silly question, but on the command line, did you put the url in quotes? The ampersand has special meaning when unquoted (run in background). I can get the courses list just fine.

Comment: gah, that might have been the issue. I wasn't using quotes

Comment: @nikc.org: Indeed, that was the issue. Care to post it as an answer so I can accept

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When using curl on the command line, you must enclose the url in quotes if it contains an ampersand (`&`) because it has special meaning on unix systems.